# Can only use @graph keyword for schemas of same type?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, json-ld

I have a webpage that has three things:
1.A medical condition
2.A doctor
3.Review Section
4.Three Videos

I want to write a schema for the page
I have written the schema below but left information blank as it is private

I have used @graph keyword to combine the various types of schemas
However, according to user https://stackoverflow.com/users/271450/jonathan
in the comments you can only use @graph keyword for schemas of same type.

Is this true?
Is the use of @graph keyword in the schema correct?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "MedicalCondition",
            "associatedAnatomy": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "name": "",
            "signOrSymptom": [
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                }
            ],
            "possibleTreatment": [
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "description":"."
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "description":""
                }
            ],
            "typicalTest": {
                "@type": "",
                "usesDevice": {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "procedure":""
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Perosn",
            "name": "",
            "affiliation": "",
            "alumniOf": [
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                }
            ],
            "": [
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "@type": "",
                    "name": ""
                }
            ],
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewBody": "",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "",
                "ratingValue":,
                "worstRating": ,
                "bestRating": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": {
                "@type": "",
                "name":""
            },
            "reviewBody": "",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "",
                "ratingValue": ,
                "worstRating": ,
                "bestRating": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewBody": "",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "",
                "ratingValue": ,
                "worstRating": ,
                "bestRating": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewBody": "",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "",
                "ratingValue": ,
                "worstRating": ,
                "bestRating": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewBody": "",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "",
                "ratingValue": ,
                "worstRating": ,
                "bestRating": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "position": ,
            "name": "",
            "url": "",
            "thumbnailUrl": [
                ""
            ],
            "uploadDate": "",
            "duration": "",
            "contentUrl": "",
            "embedUrl": "",
            "interactionStatistic": {
                "@type": "",
                "interactionType": {
                    "@type": ""
                },
                "userInteractionCount": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "VideoObject",
            "position": 2,
            "name": "",
            "url": "",
            "description": "",
            "thumbnailUrl": [
                ""
            ],
            "uploadDate": "",
            "duration": "",
            "contentUrl": "",
            "embedUrl": "",
            "interactionStatistic": {
                "@type": "",
                "interactionType": {
                    "@type": ""
                },
                "userInteractionCount": 
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "VideoObject",
            "position": ,
            "name": "",
            "url": "",
            "description": "",
            "thumbnailUrl": [
                ""
            ],
            "uploadDate": "",
            "duration": "",
            "contentUrl": "",
            "embedUrl": "",
            "interactionStatistic": {
                "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                "interactionType": {
                    "@type": ""
                },
                "userInteractionCount": 
            }
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph can contain any mix of entity types. Think of it as a way to add multiple entities into one script without having to nest them inside each other.